# How to add a title for a NVD3.js graph

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to add a title text over the graph in NVD3.js.

I tried the following,

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarWithFocusChart()
    .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
    .x(function(d,i) { return i })
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

chart.append("text")
    .attr("x", 200)             
    .attr("y", 100)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .text("Sample Charts");
}
```

Its (Highlighted) working for D3.js but not working for NVD3.js. I'm getting a Blank page..

I want to place the text over the Chart as like the following image (Which is created in Paint)

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use D3 to select the container SVG and append the title:

```
d3.select('#chart svg')
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 200)             
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
  .text("Sample Charts");
```

This assumes that you're using the same ID etc for the SVG as in the NVD3 examples, if not, simply adjust the selector accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a different approach, I wanted to have better control over the layout and style of the chart so instead of adding it as an text element inside the `<svg>` tag I added the title outside with help from jQuery.

```
var $svg = $('#chart svg');
$svg.parent().append('<div class="chart-title">Sample Charts</div>');
```

`chart-title` can be used to style the text element inside `svg` tags as well, but centering is much easier than having to use the width of the svg to set the `x` value like so:

```
svg.append('text')
    .attr('x', width / 2)
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('class', 'chart-title')
    .text('Sample Charts');
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution only works if you are setting the width. In my case the width was set to auto so until it created the chart it didn't have a width to refference. I actually modified the nvd3 code because I thought it was silly that some charts had titles and some didn't. There were 3 places I modified in each chart. Inside the margin section I added

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60}
    , marginTop = null
    .
    .
    .
    , title = false
    ;
```

Inside the chart function I added

```
function chart(selection) {
    .
    .
    .
    if(title) { 
        g.append("text")
            .attr("x", (availableWidth - margin.left)/ 2)             
            .attr("y", -4)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
            .text(title);
    }
```

Inside the chart options I added

```
chart._options = Object.create({}, {
        // simple options, just get/set the necessary values
        width:      {get: function(){return width;}, set: function(_){width=_;}},
        .
        .
        .
        title:      {get: function(){return title;}, set: function(_){title=_;}},
```

Then in your controller or where ever use

```
chart.title('Your chart Title');
```