# NVD3 chart top margin ensuring space for chart title does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I want to have title text similar as described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16459669/337621). I wanted to specify top margin to ensure place for it. However the margin.top seems to have no effect at all.

I specify the margin like this in javascript:

```
chart.margin({
        top: 1000,
        right: 100,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 100
    });
```

All other margins are working as expected. Try my short demo at http://jsfiddle.net/6DgVP/2/ (credits go to the [original example](http://jsfiddle.net/rustybailey/z4aZ4/) I modified) . All margins are working except top.

Is it a known issue? Can I fix it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, sounds like a bug to me. The problem is this bit of code in [this file](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/multiBarChart.js):

```
if ( margin.top != legend.height()) {
      margin.top = legend.height();
      availableHeight = (height || parseInt(container.style('height')) || 400)
                         - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    }
```

This ignores the setting of `margin.top` if a legend is shown by setting it to the height of the legend. You can of course hide the legend to get the top margin to be taken into account (which I have done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6DgVP/3/)), but you can also set the top margin of the legend to achieve this:

```
chart.legend.margin({top: 30});
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6DgVP/4/).

Comment: Ok. I thoght as well, that this is a bug. I opened an issue: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/515 . Thanks for your research.